# Mosquitto work abnormally with psk mode Suddenly

Tags: mosquitto

I used mosquitto as MQTT broker with PSK mode. My config is below:

`psk_hint hint
psk_file psk_file`

**psk_file:**

`zhimatest:3132333435363738`

It can work correctly at first. But afte working about 10 hours, below logs appeared. I also test with mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub which work normally before. And same "**psk identity not found**" error occured.

After restart mosquitto, every thing is OK.

`1471917009: OpenSSL Error: error:1408B0DF:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_KEY_EXCHANGE:psk identity not found
1471917009: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1471917009: Client connection from 127.0.0.1 failed: error:1408B0DF:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_KEY_EXCHANGE:psk identity not found.
1471917009: Client connection from 127.0.0.1 failed: error:1408B0DF:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_KEY_EXCHANGE:psk identity not found.
1471917009: Client connection from 127.0.0.1 failed: error:1408B0DF:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_KEY_EXCHANGE:psk identity not found.
1471917009: Client connection from 127.0.0.1 failed: error:1408B0DF:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_KEY_EXCHANGE:psk identity not found.`

Comment: Having the same issue here. My feeling is that it could be a mosquitto bug and/or something related to openssl.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. pls check your psk_file.txt has a valid key and psk-identity pair.